# Kotlin: Cannot declare a argument of type mutableListOf in class definition

Tags: android, kotlin

I cannot use the `mutableListOf` in the constructor. But I can use it in the 
class body. Is this a known bug or just we cannot do it this way?

Here is my code:

```
class Model (val title: String, var listString: kotlin.collections.mutableListOf<String>, var selectedIndex: Int = 0) : FormFieldModel(FormFieldType.SELECT_BOX) {
    var iad = mutableListOf<String>()
}
```

And I get `Unresolved reference: mutableListOf` in the constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mutableListOf` is a function. What you need is a type. So you should use `MutableList` instead.

```
var listString: MutableList<String>
```

Or, if you want to provide a default value to `listString`, you need to write it like this:

```
var listString: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `mutableListOf` is a library function, being part of standard kotlin library.

```
fun <T> mutableListOf(vararg elements: T): MutableList<T> (source)
```

It gives you a `MutableList<T>` which is the **return type** and also has to be the parameter type of your `constructor`. To fix this, just make your `listString` a `MutableList`.

```
class Model (val title: String, var listString: MutableList<String>, var selectedIndex: Int = 0) : FormFieldModel(FormFieldType.SELECT_BOX) {
    var iad = mutableListOf<String>()
}
```